A proof on a Cauchy problem
I am trying to prove the following statement:
Let $y(x):I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the solution, defined on the maximal interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ of the Cauchy problem
\begin{equation*}
y'=y^2+f(x)\text{, } y(0)=0
\end{equation*}
where $f$ is a continuous and strictly positive function. Then, $\sup I\in\mathbb{R}$.
So, if $I=(x_-,x_+)$ (open neighborhood of $0$), I have to show that $x_+<+\infty$. I can try by contradiction, but the problem is that it is not absurd that $y$ is defined on the whole real line: $y'$ is strictly positive, so $y$ is strictly increasing and the limits $\lim_{x\to x_-}y(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_+}$ are well defined. Moreover, the latter can be both finite and infinite...neither of these two cases is impossible.
The only idea I have is that, since $y$ is strictly increasing and $f>0$, then the derivative $y'$ increases "too much" and ,at a certain point, it diverges, thus violating the criterion for local extension of the solution. However, I do not know how to formalize this.
Do you have any suggestion (not a complete proof, just a suggestion)?
Thanks for any help and merry Christmas!

Have you tried the simplest of examples?

With Wolfram Alpha I tried $y'=y^2+x^2+1$, or $y'=y^2+|x+1|$, and in these cases the solution has a vertical asymptote for $x>0$

What about $f=c$ by hand?

Suppose $x_{+}  = +\infty$.
We have $y' > y^2$, for $x > 1$,  $\int_1^x\frac{y'}{y^2} > x - 1$. So
$$\frac{-1}{y(x)} + \frac{1}{y(1)} > x - 1$$
We deduce $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x) = 0$. Contradiction because $y(0) = 0$ and $y$ is strictly increasing.

Think about signs here. You must have $y(x)<0$ for $x$ large, which is difficult when $y$ is increasing,

@TedShifrin $y(x) < 0$ for $x$ large is another contradiction!

But it’s part of your contradiction. Why is it a contradiction for $y$ to approach $0$?

@TedShifrin $y$ is strictly increasing and $y(0) = 0$

As this is a Riccati equation, you can also use the parametrization $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ resulting in the oscillation equation $u''(x)+f(x)u(x)=0$, $u(0)=1$, $u'(0)=0$. As the variable frequency $f$ is bounded below, $f(x)\ge w^2$, this gives an upper bound $\frac{2\pi}{w}$ for the length of the oscillations and thus $\frac{\pi}{w}$ for the maximal length of a root-free interval. Or in more clear terms, the direction of the vector $(u'(x),u(x))$ rotates around the origin with a minimum angular speed, thus aligns regularly with all the (half-)axes. This ensures lots of roots. The exact claim is the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem.
Any root of $u(x)$ is a vertical asymptote for $y(x)$. The first positive root, which exists, is thus the supremum of $I$.
